# How to Update an Account field Monthly based on case statement?

Tags: scheduled-apex, flow

What is the best way to update (scheduled) a field in an object based upon case statements on other fields?

Example, 
On the `account` object we want to update the `Rating` field on the 1st of the month.
When the `last_order_date field >= 90 days`, update the `rating` field to `"Lost"`

When the `last_order_date field >= 30 days` and `last_order_date field < 90 days`, update the `rating` field to `"Call Account"`

We have several other case statements but thought it might become redundant here.

Thank you!

Comment: Is last_order_date field on account object?

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do it via Time Based Workflows:

**Lost**

1. Criteria, created or edited to meet criteria
2. Rating != lost && != Call Account

Execute 90 days from last_order_date - Update to 'lost'

**Call Account**

1. Criteria, created or edited to meet criteria
2. Rating != lost && != Call Account

Execute 30 days from last_order_date - Update to 'Call Account'

But it could be a nightmare to maintain depending on any additional logic and Rating values.

Another option would be to simply run a daily batch that evaluates the records and updates them accordingly. In this case, for me at least, the clicks not code mantra goes out the window. Much easier to see the logic in a batch then scattered across workflows, formulas, etc.

Comment: Sorry I did not receive an alert that there was a reply.  I am not 100% familiar with Time Based Workflows and setup a test to run on just "Lost".  Even though it is time-based on that field, Do I now have to run something to update all account records so they are now checked against that workflow?